# pgf package installation error

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, miktex, installing

I'm a big fan of this community, since I always find an answer to my problems. Just not this time. I have a new computer (from my company) and I installed MiKTeX with the option of installing packages on the fly. I'm also using a Proxy Server to download the packages and I use TeXStudio. So far so good. It works for pretty much all the packages, but I get an error when I try to use the pgf package for tikz:

File 'tikz.sty' not found

The logfile gives the following error

[image: Log File]
So I tried to download the package directly from the Package Manager, and I get the same error

[image: Error Package Manager]

I also downloaded the package myself, unpacked it, and added the root directory in the MiKTeX options... still doesn't work.
I asked a colleague to try to install the package herself, and she got the same error.

Any Ideas how to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Something on your computer is denying miktex the right to write this jpg in the folder. This could be some policy setting, or an overaggressive virus protection. Ask the IT of your company.

Comment: I see you are using ftp protocol. Where I am, behind a university firewall, ftp is blocked. I can only download via http. Perhaps that applies to you? If so, change the repository where MiKTeX gets stuff, to one with http.

Comment: I never had this problem before, but now I am having it now. Besides, I can't access the MiKTeX web page. Perhaps thate there's a connection betwwen these tings.

Comment: I’m having the same problem at the moment. For reference, I was able to install packages just fine yesterday. I can also confirm that the miktex.org site is down.

Comment: The MikTex site is back up and I can install packages again. Can you check if its working for you now?

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers and the help. I tried some things but couldn't really solve the issue. Since I have been having some trouble with MiKTeX for some days now (not only the one in this thread) and it cost me many hours (maybe it's indeed the company's firewall), I decided to switch to TexLive and it definitely solved the problem.
It's not the solution that I wanted, I really like MiKTeX and not having all packages on my computer, but it serves the purpose! ;-)